# C read multiply data types from file

Tags: c, file

I need to read from a text file and store its points in a int array. That part I've sucessfully done with `FILE* fp = fopen( filename, "r" )`. Using `fscanf (fp, "%f", &n);` to read from the file. My file structure type is like the following (I'm storing information to build a graph btw):

```
5 9
Male Female
2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
306.414 319.601 360.589 357.510  375.473 374.654 387.245 391.020 391.540
70.051 82.289 94.062 91.496 108.617 114.345 125.313 127.948 131.628
```

I need to store the following:

- Male Female in a char array (as many as nr of point rows)
- 2003 ... 2011 in another char array (as many as points columns)
- 1 array for each row of points.

So far I have accomplished the 3rd point using  `fscanf (fp, "%f", &n)`, but I need help on how to alternate the reading from chars to ints. Is this possible to do, or do I have to split files into legend.txt and points.txt ?

EDIT: All information is not fixed-size. The logic is:

- first line nr rows / nr columns
- second line is y legend
- third line is x legend
- next lines are random, with nr columns as max

Comment: can you put it in an array and the two fscaf inside, so it alternates.
If you have the exactly same amount of registers you can read to a struct.

Comment: So that "5 9" should be "2 9", shouldn't it?

Comment: no. i need the 5 to know when to stop reading files. nr of lines to draw = 5-3, nr of points each line = 9. The first three lines are always fixed.

Comment: In your 2nd line, only two column is there, Male Female, right? or its also having 9 column, just like line number 3,4 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
int nrows, ncols;

fscanf(fp, "%d", &nrows);
nrows-=3;

fscanf(fp, "%d", &ncols);

int i,j;

// Heap allocation. Be careful, you might need more 
// space than it is available on the heap

char row_legend[nrows][SIZE];
char col_legend[ncols][SIZE];
float values[nrows][ncols];


for(i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
   fscanf(fp, "%s", row_legend[i]);

for(i = 0; i < ncols; ++i)
   fscanf(fp, "%s", col_legend[i]);

for(i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
   for(j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)
      fscanf(fp, "%f", &values[i][j]);
```